# How Can I View the Console RealTime While Also Outputing stdout and stderr to a File

Tags: c#, cmd, stdout, stderr, windows-console

I have a C# console application that I can run and watch at the console by just c typing:

```
programName.exe
```

I also can write this to a file by doing:

```
programName.exe > log.txt
```

But, when I do this, I can't view the output as it is happening. I'm force to just view the log file after the entire program has finished.

How can I do both at the same time? I want to see real-time stdout and stderr, but still write to that log file. Is there a way to do this without altering the c# applications code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Windows PowerShell is an option,  for you, you can use the `Tee-Object` command:

```
programName.exe | tee -file 'log.txt'
```

This will redirect stdout simultaneously to the console window and log.txt.  A workaround to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` is:

```
programName.exe 2>&1 | tee -file 'log.txt'
```

You may also find the responses to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278296/how-to-capture-and-display-output-from-a-task-via-windows-cmd) helpful

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any existing command can do this.
But you can write a simple new program to copy the stdin and write them to console and file. Hope this can help you.