# Process, appcmd and arguments format error. Why?

Tags: c#, windows, service, arguments, appcmd

I got this error:
**Failed to process input: The parameter 'C:\test.xml' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).**

I'm trying to export my IIS websites with appcmd but I cant use this command in C#, but if i copy past manual in cmd.exe it work. "list site /config /xml > C:\test.xml", I had also tried "list site /config /xml > C:/test.xml".

```
var pro2 = new Process();
                pro2.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe";
                pro2.StartInfo.Arguments = "list site /config /xml > C:/test.xml";
                pro2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                pro2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                pro2.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
                pro2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                pro2.Start();
                EventLog.WriteEntry(pro2.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                pro2.WaitForExit();
                pro2.Close();
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Escape characters in C#, specifically "\".

Use a double backslash or @.

Comment: Still same error. Also with "-" inside "-list site /config /xml > C:\\test.xml"

Failed to process input: The parameter 'C:\\test.xml' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).

Comment: If i use this command "-list site /config /xml > @""C:\\test.xml""" i got this errpr "Object '>' is not supported.  Run 'appcmd.exe /?' to display supported objects. "

Comment: This doesn't work: P.StartInfo.FileName = "attrib"
P.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"

But this will:
P.StartInfo.FileName = "attrib"
P.StartInfo.Arguments = """C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"""

Comment: The HRESULT=80070057 code can mean either "One or more arguments are invalid" or "The parameter is incorrect".  http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2008/10/02/appcmd-80070057-errors-when-configuring-site-level-settings.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you're trying to redirect standard output to two places (`test.xml` and `pro2.StandardOutput`) without a [tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514388/how-can-i-view-the-console-realtime-while-also-outputing-stdout-and-stderr-to-a). There won't be anything in `pro2.StandardOutput`.

Second, Appcmd.exe doesn't process the redirection parameter `>`, but cmd.exe does. That's why you can run it at a cmd.exe prompt.
For example, this works in Powershell:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "/c","c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe","list site /config /xml", ">" , "c:\temp\test.xml"
```

It's sending a string array of 5 arguments to the `cmd.exe` process.  It should be pretty easy to translate that line to C#. You can leave off the `-Verb RunAs` if you're running in an elevated session, or you have read permission.